# How to solve generic input parameter to method in java

Tags: java, generics

The following doesn't compile. 
How can I solve it?
I want a method or a way to accept generic type as input to method and to delegate it to the concrete method without using `instanceof` or reflection.

```
public class MyCoolClass {

    void doSomthing(Double x) {}

    void doSomthing(Integer x) {}

    public <T extends Number> void setMe(T in) {

        doSomthing(in);

    }
}
```

Comment: in order to compile, cast either to `Double` or to `Integer`: `doSomthing((Double)in);`

Comment: What if you remove `setMe` method?

Comment: @user7 is that a serious attempt of an answer?

Comment: I won't create such generic method since you may receive an argument like `BigDecimal x` (since `BigDecimal` extends from `Number`) and you don't have a proper `doSomthing` method to support it. Just make those methods `public` and let your API client deal with it properly.

Comment: @f1sh Not by any means :). If there is only `doSomthing` method then the method gets chosen at compile time

Comment: compiler won't accept it because he doesn't know if you actually provide all the method for every type that extends number (which is infinite)

Comment: Read about "type erasure".  Java generics are in no way similar (except cosmetic) to C++ templates.

Answer (score 1):

> I want a method or a way to accept generic type as input to method and to delegate it to the concrete method without using instanceof or reflection.

If you control the generic type, then invert the control and move the behavior into the generic type's interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void doSomething();
}
```

Then your specific implementations of `MyInterface` will know what to do and thus you avoid `instanceof` and reflection.

Comment: can u give me an example? I didn't understand it. the interface is not generic

Comment: @user1409534 is `Number` the actual interface you're dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not possible to do safely... you need the instance-of. ... however you need to ask whether your are doing the right thing here.

The only way to avoid the instance of is for the type to be known and compilation time and in that case the invoking code should be capable of calling the right concrete `doSomething` method.

Otherwise somewhere, either inside your class or the invoking code must do that annoying `instance-of`

Non-instance of alternatives would fall into using java reflection API which is far worse.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question seems to be this:
Java is not C++.  Use method overloading.

Substitute something like this for your example class:

```
public class MyActuallyFunctioningClass
{
    public Integer blam(final Integer paramName) {}
    public Double blam(final Double paramName) {}
}
```

The `Integer` version will be called when you use an `Integer` parameter
and the `Double` version will be called when you use a `Double` parameter.